# Remote Name could not be resolved

Tags: asp.net, service

While accessing a webservice which is availbale at http://recpushdata.cyndigo.com/jobs.asmx, I am getting this Exception. "Remote name could not be resolved"

Any Suggesytion..what to do..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server error you got in the previous comment is good - it means your original problem, being unable to resolve the remote host, is solved.

As to your HTTP 500 error, check the event log for that time on the remote host.  If you don't have access to it, contact its administrator.

Comment: Do you have advice for what to try to fix getting a "Remote name could not be resolved" exception?

Comment: Yes, but you really should put that in a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the URL:

http://216.10.246.91/jobs.asmx

If this works, whereever you are calling the web service from has a problem with DNS. If that does not work report back.

Comment: Server Error in '/' Application. This is what I am getting as response when I tried http://216.10.246.91/jobs.asmx

Comment: Did you do something between posting and trying this that could have fixed the problem you had with being unable to resolve the remote host?